# onTop side menu in the rightmost side of the app

Tags: codenameone, side-menu

By default, `Codename One` onTop side menu is on the left of the title area.
Is it possible to have it on the right instead?

```
Command services = new Command("  Services", servicesIcon) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    }
};
f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(services);
```

Comment: Did you try to use `addCommandToRightBar()`?  That should place the command on the _right side_ of the title...

Comment: no it only puts a command. I want whole side menu bar on the right most side

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't support putting the side menu on the right side of the UI I think there is an RFE on that but I'm not sure.

It's something we need to have for RTL/bidi (Right to left languages) which expect the UI to reverse.

Comment: Ok.. Hope this feature will be available soon. Is it possible that only side menu icon is on the right side of the toolbar?

Comment: That's technically possible. Just hide the existing icon using the theme hint and use an add material command to right side. The toolbar class has a an API to open the side menu which you can invoke. Notice that you would want to revert that once the proper bidi fix is made.